# Trying to convert array of object to object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert object from array of object in JavaScript but not working

```
[{"external_parts":"[ { "type": "D","xcor": 86.54545593261719,"ycor": 413.4545593261719} ] "}],
```

from that I want only this object

```
{ "type": "D","xcor": 86.54545593261719,"ycor": 413.4545593261719}
```

I have tried like that to convert but not working

```
var parsedValue = responseData.data.items[0].external_parts;
//convert
var result = {};
for (var i=0; i<parsedValue.length; i++) {
  result[parsedValue[i].key] = parsedValue[i].value;
}
coordinatesArray.push(parsedValue);
```

Comment: parsedValue is an array. you should not be reading key-value of the same. just read the object with index of the array element

Comment: i'm getting that json values from api and i have convert it to object like [{1,2,3}] to {1,2,3}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
   var parsedValue = responseData.data.items[0].external_parts;
    //convert
    var result;
    for (var i=0; i<parsedValue.length; i++) {
     result=responseData.data.items[0].external_parts[i]
    }
    coordinatesArray.push(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
    {
        "external_parts":[
            { 
                "type": "D",
                "xcor": 86.54545593261719,
                "ycor": 413.4545593261719
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Get the object:

```
var result = data[0].external_parts[0]

console.log(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{type: "D", xcor: 86.54545593261719, ycor: 413.4545593261719}
```

Comment: This still returns an array.  The mapping isn't really doing anything for you.

Comment: getting the same and the result is [{"type":"D","xcor":86.54545593261719,"ycor":413.4545593261719}]

Comment: @DharshanPLUV , Second option `var result = data[0].external_parts[0];` returns only object `{type: "D", xcor: 86.54545593261719, ycor: 413.4545593261719}` what you are expecting.

Comment: @DharshanPLUV updated as per your requirements.

Comment: actually my need is   [ { } ]     to    { } that is it

Comment: so it is `[{}][0]`. `[{1,2,3}][0]` returns `{1,2,3}`

Comment: still not getting can u explain ur last  answer